# local storage being wiped in ionic on iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making a mobile app w/ a rails server for the backend. The basic premise is when a user signs in successfully, the server returns a unique token and their user_id. I store only those 2 things in local storage (`window.localStorage` not any library)

`localStorage.setItem('user_id', data['id']);
 localStorage.setItem('authToken', data['auth_token']);`

I then use the token/ID to communicate with the server.

The problem, is recently in testing (app is already live w/ a couple dozen users), the token is *occasionally* not getting set or saving, and as a result, I get a 500 error. I say occasionally because sometimes it does work. I guess I'm mainly just confused. It was working fine w/ my initial pushes on the app, and works on ionic view. I don't know what has changed, as I have not changed any code.

From my standpoint and in my initial debugging, it looks like local storage is either unreliable, i need to use an angular/ionic option (not `window.localStorage`), find another way to store data like I have been (SQLite?), or it *could* be a permissions bug?

If anyone has experience something similar to this and found a viable solution, I would love to learn more about this and find a solution to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that before you choose another data store option, you must see your application in execution, try **inspect** the app in Google Chrome inspect or in Safari (case iOS), look at the localStorage proprieties using your app, I believe this is enough for you do fix your bug.

Inspect Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Inspect Safari:
http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I didn't know something like this existed and I will look into this